# If $A$ is linearly dependent than $A^T$ must be linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, independence

If $A$ is linearly dependent than $A^T$ is linearly dependent?

Comment: Do you mean that columns are linearly dependent? Yes, $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$.

Comment: @freakish that is only true if $A$ is square.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it still shows linear independence if $A$ is not square, isn't it? ($N$ Equations must have $N$ variables)

Comment: @Tomergt45 well, no. $[1\ 2]$ has linearly dependent columns but $[1\ 2]^T$ does not (it has a single column). It boils down to the question whether $rank(A)$ is equal to the number of columns of $A$. Transposition translates column independence into row independence. So I suppose it depends on what exactly OP wants.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "$N$ equations must have $N$ variables"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $A_{m \times n}$ and $B_{n \times p} \ne 0$ and $AB=0$ I can prove $A$ is linearly dependent because the columns of $B$ are a solution for $Ax=0$, I need to prove that B is linearly dependent as well, my approach was that $B^TA^T=0$ and so this makes $B$ dependent but now I'm confused

Comment: The statement that you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: Also you keep using this terminology, so let me emphasize that "$A$ is linearly independent/dependent" is meaningless in the usual language of linear algebra.  Normally, one says "the columns of $A$ are independent/dependent", or "$A$ has full column-rank".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ok, if you don't mind a quick follow-up question, can I say that the rows and columns of $B$ are linearly dependent when $A$ and $B$ are square matrices? because if $AB=0$ than $B^TA^T=0$ and $det(B)=det(B^T)=0$, thank you, I am new to linear algebra :)

Comment: Yes.  Indeed if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices with $AB = 0$, it must be the case that both $A$ and $B$ have linearly dependent rows and linearly independent columns.